# Django: Returning data from a linked table

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am doing a project that revolves around storing scores against players.  Each player can shoot several rounds, some several times.  I am trying to make a page that shows a list of the rounds shot and the number of times that round has been shot.  This will ultimately be a link to a table of those rounds.
I have been able to bring back the round id but cannot get the round name back from the linked table.  This seems such a basic thing but I cannot figure it out.

## My models are:

#### class Score(models.Model):

```
BOW_TYPE = (
    ('R', 'Recurve',),
    ('C', 'Compound',),
    ('L', 'Longbow',),
)
archer = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='scores', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
rndname = models.ForeignKey('Round', related_name='rounds', verbose_name=("Round Name"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
age = models.ForeignKey('Age', related_name='scores', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
bowtype = models.CharField(max_length=1, verbose_name=("Bow Type"), choices=BOW_TYPE)
score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
dateshot = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date Round Shot", default=timezone.now)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.archer) + ' | ' + str(self.score) + ' | ' + str(self.rndname) + ' | ' + str(self.created_date)
```

#### class Round(models.Model):

```
roundname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
maxscore = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.roundname)
```

I can return the number id of the distinct rounds using this line in views.py:

```
posts = Score.objects.values('rndname').distinct().order_by('rndname')
```

and this returns the round id as stored in the scores table but I would like the name of the round rather than its id number.

I have used this code in the html file:

```
{% for post in posts %}
      <li class="list-group-item"><b>Round Name:</b> {{ post.rndname__round.roundname }} {{ watchcount }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

and many variations thereof.

I feel that this is really simple but I cannot wqork it out.
Has anyone any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please try  `posts = Score.objects.values('rndname__roundname').distinct().order_by('rndname')` and let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: That worked brilliantly.  I had been going round and round with this. Thank you